# To sent email while creating a record

Tags: email, congo-composer

I am new to conga composer. My requirement is to sent an email with attachment to Contact when I create a Account record. Is it possible? I have tried using conga workflow, but its not working..Can anyone please help me

Comment: This should be possible even with standard functionality(Depend on data volume)...
Why do you need to use Conga?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either a simple process builder and/or Workflow process.  If you are using Conga Workflow, have you ensured that you have Workflow enabled in your environment?  Additionally, have you setup the appropriate EmailTemplate and other mandatory email parameters in your solution?  Regardless, email our team: support@getconga.com and someone will gladly jump in to assist.